# How to display text at a given position?

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

my first post and am very early in learning Python. Please be gentle.
I have a piece of code here that works but it is difficult to read the output.
I would like to display the sensors on screen statically, rather than in an ever ascending list that scrolls down the screen.
Is it possible to change the print function so it updates the temp every X seconds in a single location on the shell window? Thanks in advance

```
import os
import glob
import time

os.system('modprobe w1-gpio')
os.system('modprobe w1-therm')

def read_temp_raw(i):
    base_dir = '/sys/bus/w1/devices/'
    device_folder = glob.glob(base_dir + '28*')[i]
    device_file = device_folder + '/w1_slave'
    f = open(device_file, 'r')
    lines = f.readlines()
    f.close()
    return lines

def read_temp(i):
    lines = read_temp_raw(i)
    while lines[0].strip()[-3:] != 'YES':
        time.sleep(0.2)
        lines = read_temp_raw()
    equals_pos = lines[1].find('t=')
    if equals_pos != -1:
        temp_string = lines[1][equals_pos+2:]
        temp_c = float(temp_string) / 1000.0
        temp_f = temp_c * 9.0 / 5.0 + 32.0
        return temp_c, temp_f

while True:
    print "Sensor 1", (read_temp(0))
    print "Sensor 2", (read_temp(1))
    print "Sensor 3", (read_temp(2))
    time.sleep(2)
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Your question title doesn't really match your question contents which more about console text drawing than sensors

Comment: True, I have the sensor part working in the above code which may be helpful. Funnily enough I have been looking at using sys.stdout.write and the carriage return, but haven't yet managed to get it to work.

Comment: I have changed your title to better match your question, I hope you won't mind, and if you do, please change it so it reflects the content 

Comment: That is perfect, thanks zmo :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To always print an element at the same position in your screen, you can use some special console characters:

- the ASCII character `\r` will always overwrite the same line

so if you do:

```
# use the new format of print, not the old one
from __future__ import print_function

while True:
    print ("Sensors: {}\t{}\t{}     ".format(
              read_temp(0), read_temp(1), read_temp(2)), end='\r')
    time.sleep(2)
```

you'll only have one line that will refresh itself:

```
Sensors: 42    42    42
```

That solution works in most consoles, including windows.

if you want to always have three lines, then you need to clear the screen everytime you loop:

- the ANSI command `\33[2J` will clear the screen (it's like when you hit the keyboard binding <kbd>C</kbd>-<kbd>L</kbd>).

i.e.:

```
while True:
    print('\33[2J')
    print('Sensor 1: {}'.format(read_temp(0)))
    print('Sensor 2: {}'.format(read_temp(1)))
    print('Sensor 3: {}'.format(read_temp(2)))
```

though that solution won't work with a non-ANSI consoles.

- if you want to make more complex outputs, you can use the `blessings` library, which is based on `ncurses` and allows you to draw user interfaces in the command line.

here's how:

```
import blessings

term = blessings.Terminal()
with term.fullscreen():
    while True:
        with term.location(0, 0):
            print('--- This is the first line ---')
            print('Sensor 1: {t.bold}{}{t.normal}'.format(read_temp(0), t=term))
            print('Sensor 2: {t.bold}{}{t.normal}'.format(read_temp(1), t=term))
            print('Sensor 3: {t.bold}{}{t.normal}'.format(read_temp(2), t=term))
            print('--- This is the fifth line ---')
```

so that you don't have to care about using special characters, and just use positioning using column + rows (the `0, 0` parameters of `location()`.

that will print:

```
--- This is the first line ---
Sensor 1: 0
Sensor 2: 122
Sensor 3: 244
--- This is the fifth line ---
```

at the top of your console.

---

N.B.: as a side note it is better and safer to use:

```
def read_temp_raw(i):
    base_dir = '/sys/bus/w1/devices/'
    device_folder = glob.glob(base_dir + '28*')[i]
    device_file = device_folder + '/w1_slave'
    with open(device_file, 'r') as f:
        return f.readlines()
```

which will close the device file, even upon read failure.

Comment: Much appreciated zmo, I tried the first variant of the code - keeping all on one line. I had already tried /r but I get a weird box instead of the carriage return. So it still goes on ascending lines. I achieved the clear screen using \n *100 but \r doesnt work in this python shell. Anyway its not essential, clearing screen makes it readable for now. Ultimately I will have to log these to a db which is when things will get far more complex I am sure! Thanks again!