# How to print under a fixed banner in python

Tags: python, text, anchor, stdout, banner

I want to be able to print the standard output while keeping a banner fixed anchored at the top of the console

Is there a way to do it that is simple enough to avoid refactoring the whole code?

Comment: Without details on what you already got it is hard to answer, and since you are probably just trying to explore this topic please consider learning about the problem first through threads like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43809830/how-to-display-text-at-a-given-position), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45656335/how-to-make-text-fit-inside-a-python-curses-textbox) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2515244/how-to-scroll-text-in-python-curses-subwindow), as `curses` is the go-to library to control where text goes in a console.

Comment: thank you but my main problem is just to avoid rewriting the whole console layout through curses. My ideal is something pyfiglet like

Comment: Then you might need to wrap whatever is generating the output into a contained output and then have an `ncurse` wrapper, like in the [answer I have provided to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48697482/python-using-ncurses-when-underlying-library-logs-to-stdout).  This was provided as a last resort where the OP had no choice in the matter about the output being generated.